# Why is my Call to a Magento Block's getTemplateFile method returning null?

Tags: php, oop, magento

When I use the following code in an index controller

```
<?php
class Nofrills_Booklayout_IndexController  extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $block = new Mage_Core_Block_Template();        
        $block->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');
        var_dump($block->getTemplateFile());
    }
}
```

I expect a result something like this

```
string 'frontend/base/default/template/helloworld.phtml' (length=47)
```

However, on my system, I get

```
null
```

What's wrong with my system that it's returning `null` for a call to

```
<code>getTemplateFile</code>
```

**OR** how can I debug this myself?

Happening on Magento 1.7.0.1.

Comment: Weird problem, I'm unable to reproduce (tried several versions). Are you willing/able to supply a tar ball of the installation and the db dump?

Comment: I agree it's weird. I was asking for a customer so I don't have a tarball.   http://www.pulsestorm.net/nofrills-layout-chapter-one#comment-574707059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Vinai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485589/vinai) indicated in his [original comment on the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301351/why-is-my-call-to-a-magento-blocks-gettemplatefile-method-returning-null#comment-14879112), this issue requires a tarball to troubleshoot.

The class definition for `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` *must* be getting loaded, else there would either be output of an error regarding `include()` or non-object operation, or there could be no output at all depending on developer mode.

It should be noted that [`getTemplateFile()` was not defined](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.4.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L223) until [Magento 1.4.1.0](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.4.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php#L112). The most likely issue then is an incorrect version of `Mage_Core_Block_Template` or `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package`, whether present as modified in local or community codepool, or the incorrect version of Magento being reported. Helpful output would be as follows:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

    $block = new Mage_Core_Block_Template();
    $block->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');
    $debug = new ReflectionClass($block);

    echo Mage::getVersion();

    Zend_Debug::dump($debug->getFileName());
    Zend_Debug::dump($debug->getMethods());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this, and I was unable to reproduce the problem on a freshly installed version of 1.7.0.1.  This means there's something different about your system's configuration. Possibly a file permissions thing, possibly some changed Magento code, possibly something I'm not considering.

This means the only way left to figure out what's going on is a long hard debugging slog through how Magento determines the path to a template.  Under normal system operation this will **never** return null.  For some reason on your system it is.  I'll outline normal call stack for such a call below.  Hopefully that will give you the information you need to get your system operational.

Also, before we get to the call stack, it's possible that your inheritance chain and or Template block method has been messed with.  The `null` value is what's returned when a `Varien_Object`'s magic setter is called and no values has been set.  Check that your `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class still has it's `getTemplateFile` method, and that

```
class Mage_Core_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

abstract class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract extends Varien_Object
```

Keep in mind the file paths below assume no one's placed a class override or rewrite somewhere on your system

The `getTemplatefile` method is defined in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
public function getTemplateFile()
{
    $params = array('_relative'=>true);
    $area = $this->getArea();
    if ($area) {
        $params['_area'] = $area;
    }
    $templateName = Mage::getDesign()->getTemplateFilename($this->getTemplate(), $params);
    return $templateName;
}
```

You can see this is a wrapper to `getTemplateFilename` on the design package object.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php
public function getTemplateFilename($file, array $params=array())
{
    $params['_type'] = 'template';
    return $this->getFilename($file, $params);
}
```

Which in turn is a wrapper to `getFilename`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php
public function getFilename($file, array $params)
{
    Varien_Profiler::start(__METHOD__);
    $this->updateParamDefaults($params);
    $result = $this->_fallback($file, $params, array(
        array(),
        array('_theme' => $this->getFallbackTheme()),
        array('_theme' => self::DEFAULT_THEME),
    ));
    Varien_Profiler::stop(__METHOD__);
    return $result;
}
```

Which, in turn, is a call to `_fallback`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php
protected function _fallback($file, array &$params, array $fallbackScheme = array(array()))
{
    if ($this->_shouldFallback) {
        foreach ($fallbackScheme as $try) {
            $params = array_merge($params, $try);
            $filename = $this->validateFile($file, $params);
            if ($filename) {
                return $filename;
            }
        }
        $params['_package'] = self::BASE_PACKAGE;
        $params['_theme']   = self::DEFAULT_THEME;
    }
    return $this->_renderFilename($file, $params);
}
```

The `_fallback method also calls   the validateFile  and _renderFilename methods.`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php    
public function validateFile($file, array $params)
{
    $fileName = $this->_renderFilename($file, $params);
    $testFile = (empty($params['_relative']) ? '' : Mage::getBaseDir('design') . DS) . $fileName;
    if (!file_exists($testFile)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $fileName;
}

...

protected function _renderFilename($file, array $params)
{
    switch ($params['_type']) {
        case 'skin':
            $dir = $this->getSkinBaseDir($params);
            break;

        case 'locale':
            $dir = $this->getLocaleBasedir($params);
            break;

        default:
            $dir = $this->getBaseDir($params);
            break;
    }
    return $dir . DS . $file;
}
```

Somewhere along this path your null is getting inserted into the mix.

(If you end up finding an answer, please let us know)